# Get reference to parent activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

From Child Activity, I need to get next item in the ListView of the parent Activity.

Something like below should be perfect(not working, just exemple)

```
ParentActivity parent= (ParentActivity)getCallingActivity();
ArrayList yeahIGotReferenceToParentArray = parent.array;
```

Activity A=  Listview with 30 row.

When user Click on a row, it open a new Activity B.

From Activity B, I have a button "Next", to get the next item of the ListView on activity A.

Possible solution:
I can use a Intent to provide the full array of the listView, but a better approach can Be to get the reference to the Activity A (from activity B), so I can access value.

Comment: so what is the question sir

Comment: How to do something like this:
ParentActivity parent= (ParentActivity)getCallingActivity();
ArrayList yeahIGotReferenceToParentArray = parent.array;

Answer (score 0):

You could pass that data, while you are still in activity A, to activity B through an intent. So in your onClick() method you could do something like...

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

and in ActivityB

```
Bundle extras = getExtras();
if(extras != null){
 if(extras.containsKey("key")){
  //do something based on what the value of the data is
 }
}
```

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this but it could work!

Comment: Will work, but i'll have to pass the full array. (curiosity: are the Extra byVal or byRef?)

Comment: You don't have to pass the entire array. I'n your on click method you can get the adapter position and add one to it. For example, I believe it would look something like this.               I.putExtra ("key", getItem (getAdapterPosition ()+1);

Comment: And also..... if the array is a custom java object, you can make that class implement serializable so that you can pass it between activities.